Boot error ubuntu
I was using my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04) to reformat some SSD drives to EXT4 and suddenly my Laptop crashed, When I rebooted it, It is saying "Invalid Partition Table) and goes to Grub Rescue. I tried to recover the boot and partition using the Boot repair disk, without any success.
When I am trying to boot the system using a live flash drive, I am getting the error "incompatible license".
Why am I getting this error and how I can solve it?

Corrupted .mod files in the GRUB boot loader would result in an “incompatible license” error being returned. As such, GRUB needs to be reinstalled.

@matigo How can I do this? I get that error When I try to boot from a flash drive. Does it mean that my flash drive grub is faulty or grub on my laptop?
